# communicate with WEB Api from windows phone project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

Ive got Web API project which hosts data service. Everything is ok and I can consume it from console client using this code:

```
private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:15017/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // HTTP GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                 var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
                 foreach (var product in products)
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(product.Description);
                    Console.WriteLine(product.ShortDescription);
                    Console.WriteLine(product.Prize);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }
```

Works perfect.

Than I have windows phone 8 app. It has such a structure that I have ViewModels which create instances of IRepository interfaces. I try to connect to web api and load data from IRepository classes using the same code as in my console app but when I try to add reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting which is needed Ive got an error whiole installing package:

```
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.1.2' to PhoneApp.
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

So how can I consume web api from inside my windows phone app ?

Comment: Did you check out [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application)? The WinPhone code has reference to System.Net namespace.

Comment: yes, its sth complettely dofferemnt